# Returning a hash for each depth level of a matrix

Tags: java, ruby, algorithm, matrix

I'm working on developing an algorithm where a user can pass in a centre `geohash` and a `depth_value` and would get a hash that maps each depth with an array of geohashes at that depth.

For example, take a look at this:

`+--------+--------+--------+ 
 | xn774d | xn774f | xn7754 |
 +--------+--------+--------+
 | xn7749 | xn774c | xn7751 |
 +--------+--------+--------+
 | xn7748 | xn774b | xn7750 |
 +--------+--------+--------+`

If the user passes in `center_geohash`: xn774c and a `depth` of 1. It would return

`{depth_0: [xn774c], 
  depth_1: [xn774d, xn774f, xn7754, xn7751, xn7750, xn774b, xn7748, xn7749]
}` (if a depth of 2 was passed in, it would return an array of 16 geohashes)

Tools I have already developed:

I have access to a method that returns back a 2D matrix when you pass in the top right most geohash, and bottom left most geohash. A neighbors method is also available where it returns the 8 geohashes surrounding a given geohash, and an adjacent method that takes in a geohash and a direction and returns a single geohash in that direction.

Thanks so much

Comment: The neighbours method is a specific form (at depth=1) of a 'borders' method for a given depth d which returns all border geohashes.  Can this be generalized to work at depths > 1?

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to implement. See my answer to my question to see my solution! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a NxN matrix and then traversing it in a spiral order. Say I was iterating through the matrix in a clockwise fashion, then at every point where I move from left -> to -> right, would mean that I am at a new depth value. I would then just populate my hash for that new `depth_value_key` by appending the geo-hashes until the next time I move from the left to right direction again. Hope that helps!